# First try with RSS feeds using XML and CSS

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I'm trying to learn how to do RSS feeds, and I'm trying to make the xslt and css parts. I need the rss feed to show each item with title, description, length, and pubDate, and I'm trying to use CSS for that.

Here's what I have so far (sorry, not very good):

CSS file(rotten.css):

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

h2          {
        color:#03C;
        }

.intro      {
        font-style:italic;
        color:#666
        }
```

xslt file (rotten.xslt):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
    <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 
Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-  transitional.dtd"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title><xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/title" /></title>
<!-- create a link to the CSS stylesheet -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="rotten.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!--print out the title and description of the feed. -->
<h2><xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/title" /></h2>
<p class="intro"><xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/description" /></p>
<hr />
<!-- print out the news stories -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="/rss/channel/item" />

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/rss/channel/item">
<!-- put HTML and XSLT for displaying the stories here -->


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What do I need to add in to make that all work together? Or...have I completely messed this up and can't recover?

I know the basic structure for an RSS feed looks something like this(minus actual data):

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <title>Name of feed</title>
        <link>URL of rss feed xml file</link>
        <description>Description of feed</description>
        <item>
            <title>Item1 title</title>
            <link>Item1 URL</link>
            <description>Item1description</description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I assume that should be placed in the xslt file, but I'm not sure where...

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the CSS until you've got the data on your HTML output - you can come back to it later.

The code for displaying each item should be placed in the `<xsl:template match="/rss/channel/item">` template you've created at the bottom of the XSLT. For example (and assuming your XML fragment is correct), you could get a very basic, hyphen-delimited output for each feed by amending the template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/rss/channel/item">
    <p><!-- wrap the output in a p so it appears on one line per item -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/> -
        <xsl:apply-templates select="link"/> -
        <xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

This template will be called automatically for every item in the rss/channel so you should get all the items in a list. You can then dress this up with whatever HTML or CSS you like, and maybe look further into XSLT to find better ways of using templates to get what you want.

But hopefully that'll get you started.